Running openapi-generator-cli in a closed corporate network with a maven mirror
I am trying to run the OpenAPI generator CLI using npm but it complains that it cannot reach search.maven.org:
Command I am running in node cmd:
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i .\fail.oas.yaml -g ruby -o .\temp

Error I am getting:

Unable to query repository, because of: "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND search.maven.org"

Stack trace:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
at VersionManagerService.printResponseError (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\main.js:2:15114)
at C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\main.js:2:12422
at C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\operators\catchError.js:13:51
at OperatorSubscriber._this._error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\operators\OperatorSubscriber.js:43:21)
at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\Subscriber.js:60:18)
at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\Subscriber.js:84:30)
at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\Subscriber.js:60:18)
at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\Subscriber.js:84:30)
at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\Subscriber.js:60:18)
at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\tredfern\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\Subscriber.js:84:30)

It seems like the tool is trying to access public maven, but I'm on a closed network with no internet. We do have a maven mirror which I can access, but how do I tell the tooling to look there instead?
My .npmrc file:
registry=https://xxxxxx/repository/npm-all/ <-- this is our npm mirror
always-auth=true
init-author-name=xxxxx
init-author-email=xxxxx
init-author-url=xxxxx
email=xxxx
_auth=xxxxxxxxx9iNndxaWw=
strict-ssl=false


Have you checked your .npmrc file and configured it accordingly?

@khmarbaise yes, I believe so. The .npmrc file is configured to go to our npm mirror instead of the public one.
